# Order of parameters in ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an already existing method in my concern file, which has following number parameters define. For ex

```
module MyMethods
  def close_open_tasks(param_1, param_2, param_3 = nil)
    p param_1
    p param_2
    p param_3   
  end
end
```

But I am trying to add one more new optional parameter at the end `param_4` in the above method.
Lets say I am including this module from an api and calling it from there.

When I call the following

```
close_open_tasks("test1","test2","test4")
```

"test4" is getting assigned to param_3 arg. How can I make it assign to param_4? Since both param_3 and param_4 are optional parameters its getting trickier with order.

Comment: yes we can refactor the existing module method. How do you suggest to refactor it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use keywords arguments

```
module MyMethods
  def close_open_tasks(param_1:, param_2:, param_3: nil, params_4: nil)
    p param_1
    p param_2
    p param_3   
  end
end
```

and call it like this

```
close_open_tasks(param_1: "test1", param_2: "test2", param_4: "test4")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your method has more then two positional arguments or there is no obvious order to the arguments you should define them as keyword arguments.

```
def close_open_tasks(foo, bar:, baz:) # required
def close_open_tasks(foo, bar: 3, baz: nil) # with defaults
```

If your method should actually take a list of arguments of any length you can use a splat:

```
def close_open_tasks(*tasks)
  tasks.map do
    task.close
  end
end
```

```
close_open_tasks(task1, task2)
```

The equivilent for keyword arguments is the double splat:

```
def close_open_tasks(foo, bar: 3, baz: nil, **opts)
```

Which will provide a `opts` hash containing the additional keyword args.